# How to programmatically send a Facebook message which includes an image to a user from my friend list

Tags: javascript, facebook, messaging

I would like to ask you for advice whether is it possible to send programmatically a message in Facebook which includes an image to a user from the friend list.

There are at least to ways to send an image manually to a Facebook friend:

- drag and drop an image file into a message;
- press attach button, select an image, press Enter.

I figured out the way how to send a text message using JavaScript, but it doesn’t allow to include an image.

Your advice will be highly appreciated.

Ivan.

Comment: How about using the Facebook API?

Comment: The Chat API is deprecated and it would be against Facebook Platform Policy even if it wasn't deprecated and you used it